# MongoDB: How to insert complex schema

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a "Test" system. each test has some questions.
Each question has answers.

I'm getting a JSON to create the question from another server as:

```
{
     requestType: 'CreateNewQuestion',
     questionId: 17447,
     subject: "Math",
     subsubject: "Heshbon",
     questionText: "1+4 Equels?",
     answers: [{text : "2",rightAnswer : false},
               {text : "35",rightAnswer : false},
               {text : "5",rightAnswer : true},
               {text : "9",rightAnswer : false}]
}
```

I built 2 Schemas:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Answer' ,
{
    text: String,
    rightAnswer: Boolean
}
```

);

And

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Question' ,
{
    questionId: Number,
    subject: String,
    subsubject: String,
    questionText: String,
    answerTimeAvg: Number,
    fastestAnswer: Number,
    answers: [{ type : mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Answer' }]
}
);
```

I made a function that get the JSON and try to save it like:

```
var QuestionSchema = require('./schemas/question');
var AnswerSchema = require('./schemas/answer');

CreateNewQuestion: function (message) {

    var information = {
        questionId: message.questionId,
        subject: message.subject,
        subsubject: message.subsubject,
    }

    //Save Question
    var record = new QuestionSchema(information);
    record.save(function (err) {});
}
```

How can I create the Answers object and populate them into the question?

I tried couple of things but keep getting error,

What is the proper way?

I tried to read in "mongoosejs.com/docs" but the site is down :(

Comment: Your example doc shows `answers` containing embedded sub-docs, but your schema defines it as an array of references instead. Which is correct?

Comment: Both :) .
I'm getting a full Json but I want to separate it to 2 models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change the model to:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Question' ,
{
    subject: String,
    subsubject: String,
    questionText: String,
    answerTimeAvg: Number,
    fastestAnswer: Number,
    answers: [{ type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Answer' }]
} );
```

And save the answers first, and than use the IDs:

```
CreateNewQuestion: function (message) {

    ////////////////////////
    // Saving the answers //
    ////////////////////////

    var answers = message.answers;
    var answers_ids = [];

    for(var i in answers) {
        var answer = new AnswerSchema(answers[i]);
        answer.save();
        answers_ids.push(answer._id);
    }


    /////////////////////////
    // Saving the question //
    /////////////////////////

    var information = {
        subject: message.subject,
        subsubject: message.subsubject,
        questionText: message.questionText,
        answerTimeAvg: 0,
        fastestAnswer: 0,
        answers: answers_ids
    }

    var record = new QuestionSchema(information);
    record.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Bad = " + err);
            var result = "bad";
            message.sendReplay({result: result});
        }
        else {
            var result = "AllGood";
            message.sendReplay({result: result});
        }
    });

},
```